# Is it possible to program from I2C to SRAM and boot from SRAM on STM32G0?

Tags: circuit-design, stm32, i2c, programming, bootloader

In one of our projects, we want to program SRAM of STM32G0 slaves by using I2C from a master STM32G0 and boot them from SRAM. Is this possible? If possible, how can I do it? I could not find enough resources and examples on the Internet.

Comment: It’s possible, but there are reasons it’s not common.  A 32k binary would take around 2.5 seconds without figuring overhead at 100k bus. You’ll have to come up with a protocol, then figure out linking etc. Perhaps there are better options.  Good standard i2c devices may be much less work.

Comment: I don't know anything about the STM32G0, except that I think you just taught me that it has SRAM on-board. Can't the STM32G0 simply execute code in SRAM? If so, why can't you have code on the slave devices that accept code over I2C (hopefully the STM32G0 includes hardware support for I2C but that's not necessary), save it into SRAM programmatically, and when the transfer is complete (or an order is given) start executing code out of SRAM?

Comment: Have you read AN2606 and AN4221 from ST?

Comment: As jonk writes above - you don't need to "boot from SRAM", you just need the code execution to jump to SRAM. So you need to write "bootloader" code which turns your STM32G0 into a SPI slave which writes received data to SRAM, and then jumps there to execute it. Maybe the App Notes Kartman refers to describe that kind of thing ...

Comment: @Kartman Yes, I read these but the application notes are for booting from ROM, I want to toot from embedded SRAM. I don't know how to do.

Comment: @jonk Thank you for your comments. I mean the embedded SRAM and it has to be I2C because I want to program like 10 slaves on startup. So I need to write a bootloader to get the program from I2C to SRAM and start executing from SRAM. But how can I do that?

Comment: @brhans Thank you for clarifying. It has to be I2C. There is a lack of resources and examples on these issues.

Comment: There probably isn't one single app note which tells you how to do the whole thing. You'll almost certainly find multiple app notes which cover the various pieces though. To start with you'll need to write the code which makes your device behave as an I2C slave so that your master can write data to it. I'd probably make it look like it's an I2C memory device like an EEPROM and use the same protocol ...

Comment: ... Once you have that part working you'd need to add on the extra code to be able to send it a command over I2C to instruct it to jump from the currently running code in Flash to the downloaded code in SRAM - and that's almost exactly what any other bootloader does, so you can certainly find an app note which describes it.